# Reverse all ulimits set to 0 for root user

Tags: centos7

Working on a CentOS 7 box, I was troubleshooting something and set ulimits of the following values, in a rush, thinking this was unlimited:

root hard core 0
root hard maxlogins 0
root soft nofile 0
root hard nofile 0
root soft nproc 0
root hard nproc 0
root soft fsize 0
root hard fsize 0

I'm now unable to sudo or su to root because it has a limit of 0 logins / processes etc. Seems like such a silly mistake and I hope there is a workaround.

Does anyone know how to reverse this / boot without ulimits to edit the config file back?

The config file is owned by root and only root has write permissions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd boot with `init=/bin/sh`.

Add this as an argument to the kernel command line, and the system will give you a root shell without any initializations done. The root file system may be read only at this point, in which case you need to remount it read-write. This allows you to edit any file including the limits configuration.

To reboot, you need to remount the root file system readonly, call `sync`, wait for a few seconds, then press Ctrl-Alt-Del. There is no mechanism in place to ensure an orderly shutdown, so there is no guarantee that data is written to disks either, but remounting the root file system readonly sends all outstanding writes to the disk queue, and the `sync` command makes sure all of these are submitted and acknowledged by the disks, and there is no good reason for the disks to delay the writes afterwards, so waiting is sufficient to make sure it all goes out.